# add image to form

Tags: media

How do you add something like `<img src="" alt="">` to a form?

```
$form['image1'] = array(
  '#type' => 'img',
  '#name' => 'image1',
  '#id' => 'image1',
  '#prefix' => '<div class="existing-images">
                    <div class="existing-image">
                        <a href="" class="delete">X</a>',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

or

```
'#type'=>'image',
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Drupal 7, *img* or *image* is not a type of form element. Since you seem to associate an action to that image, you probably are looking for [#image_button](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#image_button), which formats a form submit button with an image.

Otherwise, you can use the following code.

```
$form['image1'] = array(
  '#markup' => theme('image', array('path' => $your_image_path, 'attributes' => array()))
  '#name' => 'image1',
  '#id' => 'image1',
  '#prefix' => '<div class="existing-images"><div class="existing-image"><a href="" class="delete">X</a>',
  '#suffix' => '</div>',
);
```

In Drupal 8, you can still use *image_button* as #type, but you can also use *responsive_image* when the Responsive image module is enabled.